# PyQt5: QApplication gets more and more QTimers

Tags: python, qt, memory-leaks

I'm having a strange effect with an application built in Python 3.4 using PyQt5 (and making use of asyncio and [quamash](https://github.com/harvimt/quamash), should that matter). The program does some periodic stuff, once using a separate thread and `time.sleep()` and once using an asyncio coroutine and `asyncio.sleep()`. Now as soon as one or both of those periodic operations are started, the application's memory consumption steadily increases. Using the objgraph module and some debugging, I then found that there are lots and lots of `QTimer` objects generated and added to the main `QApplication` object (and not referenced by anything else if `objgraph.show_backrefs()` is right). I could then also see this when checking the QApplication object's children directly:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
app = QCoreApplication.instance()
len(app.children())
Out[3]: 7627
len(app.children())
Out[4]: 8127
app.children()[0:10]
Out[5]: 
[<PyQt5.QtCore.QAbstractEventDispatcher at 0x6155670>,
 <PyQt5.QtGui.QSessionManager at 0x61556c0>,
 <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QCommonStyle at 0x6155760>,
 <PyQt5.QtCore.QTimer at 0x53a35d0>,
 <PyQt5.QtCore.QTimer at 0x53a3580>,
 <PyQt5.QtCore.QTimer at 0x53a36c0>,
 <PyQt5.QtCore.QObject at 0x61557b0>,
 <PyQt5.QtCore.QTimer at 0x53bbd50>,
 <PyQt5.QtCore.QTimer at 0x53bbda0>,
 <PyQt5.QtCore.QTimer at 0x6a81080>]
```

This is quite interesting (and annoying), especially when considering that I don't create any single QTimer object myself. What are those timers used for by Qt? When I manually remove all QTimer objects like so

```
for t in filter(lambda o: isinstance(o, QTimer), app.children()):
    t.setParent(None)
```

then the memory is not freed but the consumption does not increase further. The application seems to still work properly otherwise. After opening and closing some windows, the original behaviour is restored, i.e. new timers are generated and the memory consumption increases. Where/how could I do more debugging to find the cause of this?

Any hints are highly welcome!

Regards,
Philipp